# Highscore inverted? Lowscore?

Tags: single-word-requests

What term would you use in the place of "Highscore" when the lower your score is, the better?

It is to be used in a mobile game. Usually in the format:

"Highscore: X"

Where X is a positive integer

Comment: Yes, *low score* is fine.

Comment: "misere __"  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mis%C3%A8re

Comment: Why not "best score"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably just go with "Lowest Score," I think that that would be sufficient.

Comment: I suppose so, seems like there isn't a great word for this. :( I might just end up using "highscore" regardless of low being better, or maybe I'll do some poll on the different words to see which one people like the most. Regardless, I appreciate the help of everyone here, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think in fact you not only swop out "Low" for high, but perhaps replace "score" with penalty" or "fine" or some other pejorative version of "score" - I think that'll help with clarity - even a physical game like golf calls the negative score "strokes" to differentiate.

Comment: The hope was that the word would indicate that the lower the number the better it is, similarly to how for "highscore" higher is better. Which is why words such as "best score" or "record" aren't used. The score is directly related to in how many moves the player wins the game, the less the better. But we don't want it to be a negative word (penalty, fine, etc.), as it should be an accomplishment to get a new "highscore", not a punishment. @Hot